# cvSaveImage() save image to a specific directory

Tags: java, javacv

I'm using JavaCV. My program required to make a webcam photo and save it to the folder which is on the desktop.
Here is the path to the folder :

```
public static String webcamPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/folder/webcam.png"
```

That is how i save the image :

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
try {
    grabber.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    while (true) {
      IplImage  img = grabber.grab();
        if (img != null) {
            cvSaveImage(webcamPath, img);
    grabber.stop();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when the webcam starts working, it can't save the image and i'm getting this exception :

```
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: videoInput is null. (Has start() been called?)
```

So is there any way to save the IplImage to a folder on the desktop?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `grabber` isn't `null`?

Comment: the problem is only in the save path, because if i change webcamPath to "D:/webcam.png", it works

Comment: Does the folder `folder` exists?

Comment: yes, ofc. I use this path in the another part of program and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this is the flow:

- start the FrameGrabber
- start loop
- grab
- stop the grabber
- trying to grab again <<< exception occurs because grabber is not opened again

My guess is to place the open inside the loop:

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);
try {
    while (true) {
      grabber.start();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      IplImage  img = grabber.grab();

      if (img != null) {
        cvSaveImage(webcamPath, img);
        grabber.stop();
      }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your file to specific directory by adding:

```
cvSaveImage(<path>\\<imagename>, img);
```